# Binding in a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model which I can successfully bind on its own. But when I make a list of the model and loop through it my binding fails. The model looks like this:

```
public class SandwichViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSize{ get; set; }
    public IList<SizeViewModel> SandwichSizes { get; set; }

}
```

I can successfully bind some radio buttons in my view that post back by doing this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Basket", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedSize,Model.SandwichSizes[0].Id)
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedSize,Model.SandwichSizes[1].Id)
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedSize,Model.SandwichSizes[2].Id)

   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

This is where I post back:

```
    public ActionResult Add(SandwichViewModel sandwichViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           int test = SandwichViewModel.SelectedSize;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test");
    }
```

However I need multiple sandwiches to be displayed in the view. At first I just made a list of sandwiches and sent it through which didnt work, then I made a new model which just contains a List of the SandwichesViewModel.

```
public class MainViewModel
{ 
    public List<SandwichViewModel> SandwichView { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my view I looped through and gave each sandwich it's own form, like so.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SandwichView.Count(); i++)
{

using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Basket", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.SandwichView[i].Id, name = Model.SandwichView[i].Id }))
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SandwichView[i].SelectedSize, Model.SandwichView[i].SandwichSizes[0].Id)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SandwichView[i].SelectedSize, Model.SandwichView[i].SandwichSizes[1].Id)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SandwichView[i].SelectedSize, Model.SandwichView[i].SandwichSizes[2].Id)


    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SandwichView[i].Id)

    <input type="submit" />
}

}
```

However the Post is always returning back the value of 0 Id and SelectedSize. I really have ran out of ideas on how to fix this. I'm soon going to be adding checkboxes for optional ingredients but can't get any further.

Comment: Your loop needs to be inside a single `<form>` and the signature of the POST method needs to be `public ActionResult Add(List<SandwichViewModel> model)` (there would be no point generating multiple forms since you can only submit one form at a time)

Comment: Note that should be `public ActionResult Add(MainViewModel model)`

Comment: Although I need to display a list of Sandwich models, I only wish to send back a single model depending on what the user clicked on. This is because the button that they click adds their selection to a basket, the radio buttons just determine the size. If I post back the whole MainViewModel how would I know which item they even added?

Comment: Because you would have a `bool IsSelected` property in your view model (of a `int quantity` property if they can choose more than one of each item). But that assumes the user wants to add multiple items to the basket. If you just want to add one at a time, use ajax to submit the `SelectedSize` value so the user can stay on the page and select more.

Comment: Or have a (hidden) form for a single object, and display the collection as text only with an associated button which opens the form as a dialog as populates its controls from the item you clicked (using javascript/jquery) and then submit the form.

Comment: Easy to add an answer explaining why your code does not work, but cannot add an answer for how it should be done unless your question also includes details for what you want the behavior to be.

Comment: I will try to explain behaviour better. Each sandwich has 3 radio buttons for small medium and large and each sandwich has a button to add that particular sandwich to a basket. So the actual adding is done on a button that needs to be linked to that sandwich.

Comment: I know what your radio buttons do, but you have not responded to any of my previous comments.

Comment: With a single form but with multiple buttons, how would I know which button has been pressed?(since the add to basket button is how the sandwich is selected) I don't belive you can bind to a button.

Comment: First we need to understand what you really want to do. If you want to allow users to select multiple items to add to the basket, then you have a single form that generates inputs for all items (which a checkbox bond to a (say) `IsSelected` property) and post back the whole collection at once (the POST method would be `public ActionResult Add(MainViewModel model)`)

Comment: If however you only want the user to select and post back only one item, then you just generate text for the collection properties and each button then displays a form for a single `SandwichViewModel` (e.g. as a dialog) and the form controls are populated based on the selected item and you post back that form